# Reuse a function across multiple UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm able to reuse a variable across multiple UIViewControllers, by storing it in a separate Swift file in my project, but I can't seem to do the same with a function. It simply doesn't get recognized the way variables do.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare it outside of the class-body:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class OneClass{
    func notGlobal(){
      println("not global")
}

func globalMethod(string:String){
    println("its global")
}
```

Comment: This is correct. I was actually doing this part right, but I was using `self` to refer to the current view controller. I changed my global function to take a view controller as an additional parameter, and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Swift extensions: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html

If this is a function you want for all instances of `UIViewController`, you could put the method in a `UIViewController` extension.

Answer (score 1):

You can define it even in the same file, but if has to be outside of the `class` body, that makes it a global variable or function and it's accessible from anywhere.